# ListView onClickListeners

Tags: android, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener

I am trying to make long and normal `onItemClickListener` for my `ListView`. This code works but when I call the Long-click and removing my finger after the `longClickListener` was triggered `onItemClickListener` triggers too. What I'm doing wrong?

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new SubjectOnItemClick(listAdapter, getSherlockActivity()));
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
        new ColorPickerDialog(
                getSherlockActivity(),
                listAdapter,
                position
        );
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpy,`return true` instead of `return false` in your `onItemLongClick`.

Returning `true` means telling Android you already got what you want, and need nothing more. Hence, the code will stop. (not triggering `onClick`)

Comment: sure. I need to wait 5 minutes to do it.

Comment: @AskQuestion No rush, just to remind :) Some people said its work but not accepting my answer (not a big problem, though) :)